# How can I read into a webpage non-linked text with jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I know, if I would like to print links and texts of links with Jsoup I have to use this code:

```
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup").get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {
            System.out.println(link.attr("abs:href") + " - " + link.text());
        }
```

**Output: (Not the complete)**

> ```
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup#mw-head - Jump to navigation
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup#p-search - Jump to search
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_developer - Developer(s)
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle - Stable release 
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup#cite_note-1 - [1]
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup#cite_note-2 - [2]
>    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repository_(version_control) - Repository 
>    https://github.com/jhy/jsoup - github.com/jhy/jsoup
>    ...
> ```

And if I would like to print texts of entire webpage I have to use this code:

```
System.out.println(doc.body().text());
```

**Output: (Not the complete)**

> jsoup From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia Jump to navigation Jump to
>   search jsoup Java HTML Parser Developer(s) Jonathan Hedley Stable
>   release 1.11.3 [1] / 2018-04-15 [2] Repository github.com/jhy/jsoup...

How can I print the all text of doc without text of links?

**Output what I wish:**

> jsoup From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia jsoup
>   Java HTML Parser Jonathan Hedley 1.11.3 / 2018-04-15 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jsoup's `Elements` has a `remove()` method. That should remove the links from your document.

```java
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jsoup").get();
doc.select("a[href]").remove();
System.out.println(doc.body().text());
```